# Artetics Sexy Lightbox issue

Tags: css, joomla, lightbox

The project is located at [here](http://www.thelastcavalier.net).

I am creating a website for a company which specializes in comics. Nothing to advanced just some lightboxes with slides in. This I have managed to do. The website uses J`oomla 3.x` and the `Purity-iii` template.

My issue is this. All the lightboxes want to appear on a new line rather than side by side. I checked the developers website as it is a paid module. They recommended inserting the following code to have the lightboxes appearing horizontally as opposed to vertically.

```
 .artsexylightboxpreview {
display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Nothing happened. I inspected the element in chrome and the `.css` file in use is correct. I have edited line 107 also as inspection tells me this is the section of the `.css` which is controlling the box. Still nothing happens. I removed the margin as it conflicted with the display tag. The full `.css` file is below. Please let me know if you need anything else to help with solving this for me.

```css
  .artsexylightboxpreview {
display: inline-block !important;
}

#SLB-Wrapper {
  margin:0.5em 0;
  margin:auto;
  font-family:Verdana;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

#SLB-Wrapper #SLB-Background{
  position: absolute;
  left:7px;
  top:7px;
  float:left;
}

#SLB-Wrapper #SLB-Top {
  background:transparent no-repeat scroll 100% 0;
  height:28px;
  margin:0 0 0 18px;
}
#SLB-Wrapper #SLB-Top img {
  float:right;
  border:0px;
  margin:6px 10px;
}

#SLB-Wrapper #SLB-Top div {
  background:transparent no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  font-size:0;
  height:28px;
  left:-18px;
  line-height:0;
  position:relative;
  width:18px;
}

#SLB-Wrapper #SLB-Bottom {
  background:transparent no-repeat scroll 0 43%;
  height:20px;
  margin:0 18px 0 0;
}

#SLB-Wrapper #SLB-Bottom #SLB-BottomRight {
  background:transparent no-repeat scroll 100% 43%;
  font-size:0;
  height:20px;
  right:-18px;
  line-height:0;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  float:right;
}

#SLB-Wrapper #SLB-Bottom.SLB-bbnav, #SLB-Wrapper #SLB-Bottom.SLB-bbnav #SLB-BottomRight{
  height:52px;
}

#SLB-Wrapper #SLB-Bottom.SLB-bbnav {
  background-position:0 100%;
}
#SLB-Wrapper #SLB-Bottom.SLB-bbnav #SLB-BottomRight{
  background-position:100% 100%;
}

#SLB-Wrapper #SLB-Contenido {
  border-left: 7px solid #000;
  border-right: 7px solid #000;
}

#SLB-Wrapper #SLB-Bottom #SLB-Navegador{
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #fff;
  height:30px;
  border-left:0px;
  border-right:0px;
  padding:10px 0px;
  margin:0;
  line-height:11px;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}

#SLB-Wrapper #SLB-Navegador img{
  border:0px;
}

#SLB-Wrapper #SLB-Navegador strong{
  display: block;
}

#SLB-Wrapper #SLB-Bottom #SLB-Navegador img.btLeft{
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
#SLB-Wrapper #SLB-Bottom #SLB-Navegador img.btRight{
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  position:relative;
  right:17px;
}

.artsexylightbox {
 
 border: 2px solid #EEEEEE;
 display: inline-block !important;
}

.artsexylightbox_singleimage {
 cursor:pointer;
 border: 2px solid #EEEEEE;
 display: inline-block !important;
}

.artsexylightbox_singletext {
 cursor:pointer;
}

.artsexylightbox_container {
 width: 100%;
}

.artsexylightboxlink {
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.asl_next {
 background: url(../images/next.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
 float: left;
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 cursor: pointer;
 vertical-align: middle;
 clear:right;
}

.asl_prev {
 background:url(../images/previous.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
 float: left;
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 cursor: pointer;
 vertical-align: middle;
 clear:both;
}

.asl_carousel {
 float: left;
}

.asl_carousel li {
 background-image: none !important;
}

.asl_caption {
 text-align:center;
}

.asl_image_caption {
 //float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}

.asl_folder {
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center  !important;
}

.asl_folder div {
  text-align: center  !important;
}

.sexylightbox_print {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: CSS alone, without the HTML it is supposed to apply to, tells us rather little. Please go read [mcve], and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended change looks like it is being applied correctly but does not seem to make any difference.

Using a float may be more appropriate:

```
.artsexylightboxpreview {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This worked a treat and I have no idea why i never thought of it.
Thank you for your time, much appreciated.

Comment: @AdamTwilley Please give credit where credit is due.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/352329